# How do I get the position in an array using an index from another array?

Tags: c#, arrays

I am creating an app which user selects from choice of pizzas and drinks.
I use an array list for the pizza selection
From the form using check boxes; what do I need to do if all 5 check boxes are checked then get all the data from the array

here is the code from the class

```
namespace order
{
    class Menu
    {
        string[] pizza = {"Cheese and Ham", "Ham and Pineapple", "Vegetarian", "MeatFeast", "Seafood" };
        double[] price = {3.50, 4.20, 5.20, 5.80, 5.60 };

        public string GetMenuItem(int select)
        {
            string choice = pizza[select];
            return choice;
        }
```

---

---

this is the Form code

```
namespace order

{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        Menu menuMaker = new Menu();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            if (checkBox1.Checked)
            {
               label1.Text = menuMaker.GetMenuItem(0);
            }


        }
    }
```

if one is checked then the form displays that result but if I wanted to select all check boxes it requires to show them all.

Comment: ArrayList is a very specific type within the framework (system.collections.arraylist). Don't say "Array list" when you just mean an array.

Comment: Do you have also 5 labels?

Comment: Check out my answer, you can create checkboxes from your menu list, no need for putting checkboxes for each item manually on form. Just to learn that you can ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach to solving this would be to switch from a `Label` to a [ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.aspx). Then you can add as many items as have been selected. If they select 3, you add 3, if they select all 5 you add all five.

Example using a listview -

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Menu menuMaker = new Menu();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listView.Clear();

        if (checkBox1.Checked)
        {
           listView.Items.Add(menuMaker.GetMenuItem(0));
        }
        if (checkBox2.Checked)
        {
           listView.Items.Add(menuMaker.GetMenuItem(1));
        }
    }
}
```

As an aside. You may want to consider creating a helper class for the pizzas that would include the price. Something like -

```
class MyMenuItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
}
```

Than you can hold just an array of menu items and you have the price and name together in one class.

Further recommendation - you may want to consider renaming your `Menu` class to `MyMenu` so that it does not conflict with the `System.Windows.Forms.Menu` class.

Comment: Thank you I have accomplished the problem of adding items, and your feedback on the code is good I am going to work on the properties

Answer (score 0):

Better but not nice also, you have to add panel1 to form:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        list = new List<CheckBox>();
    }
    List<CheckBox> list;
    Menu menu;
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        menu = new Menu();
        int i = 10;
        foreach(var item in menu.pizza){
            CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox();
            checkBox.Text = item;
            checkBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(10, i);
            i = i + 30;
            list.Add(checkBox);
            panel1.Controls.Add(checkBox);
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count;i++ )
        {
            if (list[i].Checked)
            {
                label1.Text += menu.GetMenuItem(i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and changes to menu:

```
class Menu
{
    public readonly string[] pizza = { "Cheese and Ham", "Ham and Pineapple", "Vegetarian", "MeatFeast", "Seafood" };
    public readonly double[] price = { 3.50, 4.20, 5.20, 5.80, 5.60 };

    public string GetMenuItem(int select)
    {
        string choice = pizza[select];
        return choice;
    }
}
```